# Какой драйвер для wifi устройства выбрать?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, железо, драйвер

На ноуте установлен Debian 8.5 c gnome. При установке системы почему то драйвера для wifi не установились (ядро не содержало) и следовательно в правом верхнем меню список `wifi` сетей не появился. Через обычный `LAN` подключение к интернету есть.

набрав

`lspci | grep -i wlan` выводится

`0b:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)`

для этого контроллера [тут](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx) написано установить через
`apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

а [тут](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Dell/Inspiron6400/lenny)
через `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi`

какой из них выбрать ? ноут: `Dell Inspiron 6400`

Comment: Поставить сначала один, перезагрузиться. Если не поможет - удалить, перезагрузиться и поставить другой.

Comment: @donRumata если поставится неправильный драйвер ничего не сломается? какие проблемы могут возникнуть ?

Comment: В 99% ничего. В оставшемся 1% может произойти всё что угодно, вполть до взрыва ближайшей АЭС или тепловой смерти вселенной. Так что если в новостях проскочит что-нибудь про надвигающуюся чёрную дыру - мы будем знать кого (и чей ноутбук) в этом винить.

Comment: iwlwifi насколько я помню для Intel, а у вас broadcom. К тому же указанные пакеты не содержат драйверов (скорее всего по зависимостям приносят, и то не факт).