# Не работает Wi-Fi модуль в Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

Столкнулся с тем, что после установки системы нет Wi-Fi подключений, напрямую через Ethernet интернет передается, но именно через Wi-Fi никак.

Через команду: `ip address` определяет лишь Ethernet, модуля Wi-Fi опять же нет.

Comment: Там есть фишка, что вайфай отключен аппаратно - кнопкой. Пробуйте комбнации Fn+кнопки с функциями

Comment: Не помогло, 0 реакции со стороны системы(

Comment: нужно больше информации о компьютере. dmesg, что говорит про вайфай?

Comment: Вывод `lspci`, Модель Wi-Fi контроллера, `uname -r`, "в студию"!

Comment: Установите firmware-misc-nonfree пакеты и глянте firmware-* для вашей карты

Comment: И не будет WiFi в начале после установки. Эта та единтсвенная тема в Debian которая всегда меня бесила (хоть я и с большим уважением отношусь к данной системе). Добавь в вопрос выводы которые тебя просят, чтоб понять что за модуль стоит, если же эта информация конфиденциальна (всё ок), то проверни всё это самостоятельно. Добавь в `sources.list` как написали в ответе `non-free` репозитории (добавлять по пути `etc/apt/sources.list` если не в теме). Если что не понятно и не пошло напиши в комментариях (чтоб к кому-то обращаться и человек это увидел перед ником ставь `@`)

Comment: Также используй Synaptic он у тебя по умолчанию установлен, там всё что надо есть

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782667/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565300/262779 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/737088/262779

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Скорее всего драйверы в разделе non-free

Далее драйверы для сетевых карт

```
apt-get update

apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

Перезагрузка

Comment: Это если карточка Realtek ) , а если от Intel надо выбрать соответствующую. В принципе в Synaptic всё очень даже видно, что для чего